# Is multiple type-casting in python bad?

Tags: python, casting

Say I have a variable in python called `my_boolean = False`
I want an end result to be: `my_bool = "0"` 
The only way i can think of doing this is. 
`my_bool = str(int(my_boolean))`, a double type-casting.

Is there a better way of doing this?
Disadvantages? Advantages? 
What happens internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
my_bool = '01'[my_boolean]
```

---

There seems to be a time difference between your approach and what is above:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("'01'[b]", "b = False")
0.10460775769296968
>>> timeit("str(int(b))", "b = False")
0.8879351199904466
```

Is it something to lose sleep over? Definitely not. I'm sure there are people who would call your current approach more Pythonic and prefer that over this. In other words, no, there is nothing wrong with what you're doing.

Comment: Very interesting answer for me. I saw it for first time passing bool in slice.

Comment: I've never seen such behavior before! ah, that's sad. Could you link me up to the documentation, arshajii? This certainly looks interesting and it's faster, as you pointed out.

Comment: @madCode Strings can be indexed, since they are a [sequence type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). Further, `bool` is a subclass of `int`. When used in an `int`-context, `False` is `0` and `True` is `1`.

Comment: Nice approach, not so pythonic but hey gets the job done efficiently.

Comment: @Houdini It isn't more efficient than the conditional expression[see my updated answer for the correct benchmark], and it's surely less readable(at least for people not used to index with booleans).

Comment: @Bakuriu You should try storing `'01'` in a variable and then timing `zero_one[my_boolean]`. I'm not sure if that will be faster than the conditional expression, but it should be faster than `'01'[my_boolean]`.

Comment: Why would it be faster? I have checked a bit with `timeit` and they seem equally fast, as expected since the bytecode is the same except for the difference between `LOAD_FAST` and `LOAD_CONST`, which are about the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator:

```
'1' if my_boolean else '0'
```

Comment: I thought of this, but it brings a "branching operation" into the picture. Wasn't too sure if that would be efficient, when compared to type casting.

Comment: @madCode In python(actually CPython) comparisons aren't heavy operations. That's because the code executed, the one of the interpreter, is so full of branchings that branch prediction cannot run full speed in any case. Often using branching is faster then avoiding them[this changes if you use an implementation that uses JITs or similar!]

Comment: +1 Personally, I find this to be the most Pythonic approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could use a dictionary mapping like this:

```
bool_dict = { False : '0', True : '1' }
my_boolean = bool_dict[False]
```

Not sure if it is more efficient, I would imagine so since it is just hash look up in a map, generally an O(1) operation.

Comment: o(1) + the space that stores the bool_dict in memory. so the trade-off is debatable. but yeah, that's an option, not sure if its the best. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never assume performances of operations. Profile and benchmark:

```
In [7]: value = False

In [8]: %%timeit bool_dict = {False: '0', True: '1'}
   ...: my_boolean = bool_dict[value]
   ...: 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 47.7 ns per loop

In [9]: %timeit my_boolean = str(int(value))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 420 ns per loop

In [10]: %timeit my_boolean = '0' if value is False else '1'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 50 ns per loop

In [11]: %timeit my_boolean = '01'[value]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 52.1 ns per loop
```

As you can see the `str(int(value))` is *much* slower than the rest because function calls have high overhead.

Note how the branching operation is mostly equal to the dictionary look-up[try it a few times and you'll see the two versions exchange timings], but *it's more readable, so use it*.

I personally find the conditional expression version easier to read than the original `str(int(value))`, even though *there isn't anything inherently wrong with using two conversions*, and in other situations this may be the easier solution.

<s>The version `'01'[value]` is the fastest, but I believe you should prefer readability over performances, especially if you did not prove that this conversion is the bottleneck.</s>

Note that using an identifier instead of the explicit constant `False` I discovered that this:

```
'01'[False]
```

Is optimized by the interpreter to the expression `"0"`:

```
In [14]: import dis
In [16]: def test():
    ...:     a = '01'[False]

In [17]: dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ('0') 
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a) 
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Hence the benchmark I did before wasn't correct.